# Database Reverse Engineering (DBRE) Add-On. Schema(s) do not exist or does not have any tables

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-roo

I am try using Roo Database Reverse Engineering (DBRE) Add-On revert my MYSQL data base . when i introspect the database using command

```
 database introspect --schema demohibernate
```

I get error

```
Schema(s) 'demohibernate' do not exist or does not have any tables. Note that the schema names of some databases are case-sensitive
```

I checked the schema (database) demohibernate is exist in my database. I check the database config of project by roo command

```
database properties list
```

I get the result

```
database properties list
database.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
database.password = 123456
database.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306
database.username = root
```

the username and password is correct. I installed the driver for MYSQL database. I don't know how solve it. Thank for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note MySQL doesn't use schemas, so your command must be:

```
roo> database introspect --schema no-schema-required
```

Moreover the target database name must be contained in the JDBC URL connection string:

```
roo> database properties list
database.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
database.password = 123456
database.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demohibernate
database.username = root
```